# How to change the website look and feel by changing the design location under page properties

Tags: aem

I have a requirement where I have 2 clientlibs having different CSS files for my website. The business author should be capable of switching the website look and feel by just changing the path of the design under page properties. While I am able to achieve that requirement by changing the clientlib categories name referred in my JSP of base template of my site, can the same thing be achieved by the business author without actually performing a code level change? Basically, he should be able to select the design path present under the page properties section, and selecting a different design should change the look and feel of the website. Please let me know how this can be achieved.
Note: I have placed my clientlibs under **/etc/design/proj-name/** path

Comment: People who downvote, can you please provide a reason as well? Helps in understanding what is wrong with he question. I am not an expert on AEM. Just learning it.

Answer (score 0):

The foundation page component is designed to include css link in the head if a file called static.css is present under the design. It's done through the [design](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/designer/Design.html#getCssPath()) object.

If you have different css in the static.css file under different designs then the look and feel will change with the design. However you will be stuck with one file and cannot leverage the utility of client libs.

[This](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/designer.html) adobe doc suggest's doing something like this for css and related images 
`<%= currentDesign.getPath() + "/static/img/icon.gif %>`

Data from design dialogs is stored under the design , swapping designs to change look and feel will cause data inconsistencies too.

Why not add a selection widget to the page and use it's value to selectively include different client lib categories instead of relying on the design.